How does GCC generate ARMv7 assembly for large immediate values?
I'm currently learning about compiler backends and came across a question while studying some ARMv7 assembly generated by GCC. I'm not entirely sure about this, but I'd appreciate any insights.
Given the following C code:
int a = 0;
a += 0xffffff;

The corresponding ARMv7 assembly generated is:
add     r3, r3, #16711935
add     r3, r3, #65280

Here:
16711935 = 0xff00ff
65280    =   0xff00  

As far as I understand, the add instruction uses an imm12, which consists of an 8-bit value and a 4-bit rotation field. However, 0xff00ff doesn't seem to fit the valid imm12 encoding format.
Could someone clarify how GCC generates this assembly? Is it handling the immediate value in a specific way that I’m not aware of, or am I misunderstanding something about the add instruction? I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or explanation.
You can see the full code on Godbolt.

It's using a thumb encoding. See Table A5-11 Encoding of modified immediates in Thumb data-processing instructions in the manual.

It's at F1.7.7 in the A-profile Architecture Reference Manual.

Re: how does GCC generate the assembly: How to know that a certain number can be represented as 32 bit immediate in ARM? links GCC source code.  I didn't check whether the linked code is for ARM or Thumb2 immediates, but if it's only ARM, Thumb2 is probably somewhere else in the same file.

ARMv5 and earlier MOV and MVN operands  Since, this time, there are various MOV op-code extensions.  Sometimes they are denoted as MOV.w, etc.  There are different 'forms' of MOV encodings such as shifted and replicated.  Select compile to binary in output on godbolt to observe the difference.  One is 32bit and the other is 16bits.

What part of the documentation are you struggling with?

Thanks a lot! I think I get it now. It's using thumb encoding, and adding -marm makes the behavior match my previous expectations.
